# What type of ANOVA? Three types of measurement in 2 groups

Tags: self-study, anova, spss, psychology

I am working on an assignment where I am expected to use an ANOVA test to analyse a set of data.

The data set consists of two groups, the first group is a healthy group of participants, group 2 have had an operation involving a brain lesion.

Both groups have then been tested with three tests: maths, language, logical reasoning.

I am expected to test whether the brain lesions have led to any significant decrease in cognitive functions. I am not sure what type of ANOVA to use? Maybe a 2x3 mixed ANOVA? would this be the correct choice of statistical analysis?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Alex. We have a tag for homework, called 'homework', which you should add to your question. Our policy is to give hints for homework completion, not answers :)

Comment: @Placidia The tag is actually called `self-study`

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask yourself two questions: What is being measured, and why do measurements vary?

1. You are measuring responses to test scores.
2. Tests vary for 4 reasons: the person is healthy or brain damaged; Bob is different from Paul; a math test is different from a language test; and finally, if Bob does the same test on two separate occasions, he will get a different score.

two of these reasons are fixed effects and two are random. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am guessing the that you are hinting at a fixed vs random effect anova. I have done some research on it, and while it seems that it may in fact be a viable option, my past lectures and covered course material has lead me to believe that my choice is rather one of a mixed ANOVA vs a MANOVA? What I have been taught in stats as a psychology undergraduate is quite limited, perhaps this is why.  Maybe I should have specified that this was more so the dilemma I was experiencing. Am I on the right track guessing that a MANOVA could be appropriate?

Comment: a MANOVA would work, especially if you have a large sample. a mixed effects (repeated measures) could also work. if you wanted to compare the tests that would be the method. but if you just care about the brain damage, then manova is good also.

Comment: I think i will end up using a MANOVA as the brain damage is the main variable of interest for the study and report. thank you very much for the clarification, it's been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent groups that you are comparing.  If your aim is really testing: You can either (1) do a separate test of shifts in mean (or median) score for each response (math, language, reasoning) using either a t-test or else an equivalent distribution-free test (Wilcoxon-Rank Sum test). (2) If you want to be fancy and bundle all three tests into a single overall test of differences (that will also yield a cognitive 'score' from the three responses), use MANOVA, also called (since there are two groups) Hotelling's T-test.

However, it is just as likely that you really want to know how much the scores differ between groups and not just that they differ.  I'd recommend a confidence interval for the difference in scores, one interval for each response (these can be obtained from t-test software).  There are also nonparametric versions of these intervals (Hodges-Lehmann) that are fairly robust, but that's probably overkill.  Along with these, a pair of box plots for each response (math, language, reasoning) is a good idea, too.